# How to load new data in PageView on swipe

Tags: android, flutter, listview, load

Im fetching data from the server and present it to user through listView - widget and pageview,
The goal is to load let's say 20 questions, show 3 in listview and on swipe right to load next 3 and so on..

```
 int addToIndex=0;

  List<QuestionViewV1> questions = []; //Here I load relevant data from getData method...

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getData(); 
  }
       
                   ...child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: _pageController,
                        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
                        itemCount: questions.length, 
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return _pageView(addToIndex);
                        },
                      ),
```

Here I return Widget witch represent page and listview...

```
 Widget _pageView(addToIndex) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              elevation: 4,
              // margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                  return listItem(
                      ctx,
                      index,
                      "User " + questions[index+addToIndex].user.userName,
                      _timeAgo(index+addToIndex),
                       questions[index+addToIndex].id, 
                      questionTitle:
                      questions[index+addToIndex].title); 
                },
                itemCount: 3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

EDITED: here is the _getData():

```
  _getData() async {
    ResourceFetchingAuthority _resourceFetchingAuthority =
        ResourceFetchingAuthority(
            configuration: ResourceFetchingConfiguration(

                maxReturnedResourcesForFirstPage: 12,
...     



    ResourceFetchingResult unansweredQuestionsResult =
        await _resourceFetchingAuthority.fetchResources();

    /*   List<QuestionViewV1>*/
    questions = unansweredQuestionsResult.resources.cast<QuestionViewV1>();

}


 _onPageChanged(int index) {
 setState(() {
     addToIndex=addToIndex+3;
});
```

So in given example I will get 3 questions per page in listview but every other page will have same set of questions, I need whe swipe to load 3 new questions... ( the number of questions fetched is defined in getData method.(12) )

Answer (score 0):

_getData()  should called in _onPageChanged
or make it like this

```dart
 PageView.builder(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        itemCount: questions.length, 
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return FutureBuilder(
            future: _getData(),
            builder: (ctx,snap){
              if(snap.hasData){
                return _pageView(3);
              }else if(snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                 return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          );
      },
     )
```

Comment: I aded _getData() to the question.,  " maxReturnedResourcesForFirstPage: 12," returning 12 questions , to the  List<QuestionViewV1> questions = []; ,but on the every page swipe I get first 3 (same) questions from the list, I need to somehow change index of that list ?

Comment: when you call getData() multipe time it return always the same values ?

Comment: Yes, Yes, because it basically fill List with given number data (different questions) lets say 12 , so in the  _pageView(3); 
I will get page with 3 different questions, if I _pageView(12) ill get 12 different question, but idea is to, have 3 question for page,
inside pagevewer and on swipe to load 3 new questions (currently it load 3 same question co's index not changing) 
Sorry if im  not clear.

Comment: I think I need to use some "persist" state for the index, so when i swipe, index will continue where it was...

Comment: you can get all question and split them on number of page that you want to show
you have 20 question you want to show only 3 question per page  so you have in total  7 page 
_pageView get current page and all question and it calculate range of question that will show

Comment: Hi, ty and sorry for my late response, can you show me example how to split questions in your last response?
I have some results with, manipulating index number from onPagechange and adding to the index from listview but i don't like this solution, ill edit original post..